# Visual Studio 2010 and IIS (creating website error)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis

I have added an IIS website in IIS Manager.However, when I choose HTTP in VS 2010 and select open, it shows a window writing there:creating the website'www.test.com' and then the following error comes up:

> Unable to create the Website 'http://www.test.com'.The server returned an invalid response.Please try again.If the problem persists,contact your server administrator.

I am very new to IIS and ASP.Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Run Visual Studio in Administrator Mode

Comment: I tried that.I just get the same error.

Comment: Read/Write Permision in administrator account?

Comment: and also check IUSER permision

Comment: where should I check these permissions?

Comment: check link [Reference link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19830/How-to-Access-Network-Files-using-asp-net)